# I cannot get hot water in my shower without turning on the hot water to my bathtub

Tags: plumbing

I cannot get hot water in my shower without turning on the hot water to my bathtub.  I had a plumber come out and completely change out the valve in the bathroom and I’m still having the same problem. I also have this problem in the second bathroom where you have to turn on the sink hot water To get the shower To be hot...  After paying a plumber to fix each valve in each shower and still having the same problem... I’m frustrated.. any advise?

Comment: Do you have a tank hot water heater or a tankless?

Comment: All tankless water heaters require a minimum flow for the heater to stay on. With some heaters the minimum is so high that one shower fitted with a low flow head is below the minimum for the heater to stay on. The minimum in some of these tankless heaters can be adjusted, but you might have to turn down the heater to give lower temperature hot water so you use a higher flow of hot that is above the minimum to keep the heater on.

Comment: it probably just takes a long time for the hot water to travel from your water heater through the constraints of a low-flow head, whereas your tub and sink move much more water, and thus heat up much faster. try waiting 10 mins for the shower alone to heat; i bet you $5 it will. if so, pipe insulation would help somewhat.

Comment: Do you have one of those cartridge fiters on your shower?

Comment: @Michelletg, make sure to report back as we all are curious on your findings.